# React: put ref in context

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

## How put a refs in context to reduce a spaghetti code!

this is my App component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Home from './Components/main/Home'
import About from './Components/main/About'
import Experience from './Components/main/Experience'
import Services from './Components/main/Services'
import Portfolio from './Components/main/Portfolio'
import Contact from './Components/main/Contact'
import Footer from './Components/main/Footer'
import Testmonials from './Components/main/Testmonials'

// Import context

function App() {
  const [hashtag, setHashtag] = useState('#home')
  const homeRef = useRef()
  const aboutRef = useRef()
  const experienceRef = useRef()
  const servicesRef = useRef()
  const portfolioRef = useRef()
  const contactRef = useRef()
  const testmonialsRef = useRef()
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll(event) {
      if (window.scrollY >= contactRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#contact-me')
      } else if (window.scrollY >= testmonialsRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#testmonials')
      } else if (window.scrollY >= portfolioRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#portfolio')
      } else if (window.scrollY >= servicesRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#services')
      } else if (window.scrollY >= experienceRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#experience')
      } else if (window.scrollY >= aboutRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#about')
      } else if (window.scrollY >= homeRef.current.offsetTop - 250) {
        setHashtag('#home')
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <div className='App'>
        <div className='container'>
          <Home hash={hashtag} ref={homeRef} />
          <About ref={aboutRef} />
          <Experience ref={experienceRef} />
          <Services ref={servicesRef} />
          <Portfolio ref={portfolioRef} />
          <Testmonials ref={testmonialsRef} />
          <Contact ref={contactRef} />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </React.StrictMode>
  )
}

export default App
```

- usage of hashtag state for send it to Home => Nav, then in nav make if condition for each nav link as `className={hashtag === "#about" ? 'active' : ''}`
- I used `useRef` in App component and forward this ref for each section in my page by `forwardRef`, that help me get offsetTop for each section to change navigations `className` by change state

How can I put all of these refs and state in single context to make a clean code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

##### Hiding the refs in a context is **not** a clean solution

The only thing that you would be achieving is to hide the declaration of the refs. That code belongs here, in the component, there is no need to move it into a context, since it wouldn't make sense for those refs to exist in another component!

So context is definitely not the use case for "reducing spaghetti code" in this case.

If you want to reduce immediate complexity when reading the component, you can move the handleScroll function to be outside of the component, or into another file under the same directory.

Comment: There is not a method to reduce a code of this many refs? my code is best code style?  there is no another way to reduce forwardRef in every section? *Thanks a lot!*

Comment: If you really want to extract the refs code, you may need to create a component that encapsulates the movement between refs, let's say the component receives a list of all these sub components home/about/experience. And internally assigns the refs to each passed component. That would move the complexity of the refs elsewhere. But you need to decide if that abstraction is worth the price, as for me, the code is simple enough, as i said, maybe i would move the scroll function.